# Are there any continuous-time stochastic processes in which transition probabilities are discontinuous functions over time?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, algorithms, computational-complexity

In stochastic processes, like homogeneous Markov processes, Poisson processes, Queueing systems etc., the functions that represent (transition) probabilities are continuous over time. This is also very convenient mathematically, since it allows further useful analysis to be done, such as transition rates in Markov processes.

I recently read a paper ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.07401 ) where a stochastic process is described, with probabilities being discontinuous at an infinite (!!) number of points. According to the paper, it shows the problematic nature of a certain class of algorithms with which the process is associated.

Are there any continuous-time stochastic processes with discontinuous transition probabilities or is it fundamentally incompatible with mathematical/physical reality?? I would like an answer for stochastic processes describing real phenomena/systems, not for theoretically/artificially constructed processes.

Comment: Certainly there would be reasonable models of continuous time stochastic processes with discontinuous transition probabilities. Imagine (for example) a model of queuing to pay for ticket, where there is a completely standard service time unless tickets are being bought for tomorrow in which case you get to choose your seat.

Comment: The transition kernel $k_t(\cdot,\cdot)$ of the Markov process defined by the (deterministic) right shift on the real line is given by $k_t(x,\cdot) = \delta_{t+x}$ for each time $t \ge 0$ and each real number $x$ (where $\delta_y$ denotes the Dirac measure at $y$ for each real $y$). Is that sufficienty discontinuous for your purposes?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks for your answer,Anthony! Would you be willing to provide more details for the example you gave? I would like to understand better how a function representing probabilities in your example is discontinuous over time. Thanks

Comment: It’s actually possible to build quite simple physically motivated discontinuous _quantum_ Markov process. I suspect the same holds for the classical version. If you are interested I can post an answer.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thanks for your answer, Jochen! If I understand it correctly, it is indeed discontinuous. But isn't it a bit "constructed" given that the right shift is deterministic?

Comment: @lcv Thanks for your comment, lcv! You said the magic word, "quantum"! But I would like to clarify that I am interested in the **transition probabilities being discontinuous**...just clarifying it...because "discontinuous quantum Markov process" may refer to something else

Comment: @Robert_Lewis Hahaha definitely. I'm talking about an ODE of the form $\dot{\rho}(t) = L(t) \rho(t)$ where the generator $L(t)$ is discontinuous in $t$. The diagonal part of $\rho$ (in some basis) is a probability vector and its evolution is described by a stochastic matrix (called the Pauli equation), let's call it $P(t)$. The $L$ that I'm talking about are so called Davies generator, these are the quantum version of the classical generators satisfying detailed balance. There is a well defined situation in which $L(t)$ and $P(t)$ are discontinuous in time.

Comment: @lcv Thanks a lot, lcv! Very useful! I will need some time to have a good look on this! Any idea as to which phenomenon is described in this "well defined situation" that you say? And any ideas for a classical-mechanics example?

Comment: @Robert_Lewis: Well, I'm not sure whether I'd consider a deterministic process to be "constructed". At least I think that it fits your requirement of "describing a real system", since moving things in one direction is certainly a phenomenon that occurs in reality :-).

Answer (score 1):

One example type is a jump process that jumps at certain predetermined times, as in @AnthonyQuas' [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318806/are-there-any-continuous-time-stochastic-processes-in-which-transition-probabili#comment794467_318806).

For instance, a stock price that can only make jumps when markets open, like New Zealand Stock Exchange at  UTC+12 (+13), Australian Securities Exchange at UTC+10 (+11) etc.

This can be modeled by a process $V$ such that
$$V_t=\begin{cases}S_t,&\quad 2n\le t<2n+1,\\
S_{2n+1},&\quad 2n+1\le t<2(n+1)\end{cases}$$
where $S_t$ is a geometric Brownian motion and $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Hi Bjorn, thanks for your answer! You gave me the example of V(t)...since I am not very technically-familiar with geometric Brownian motion, I guess that **the transition probability density function** is discontinuous at **t=2n+1**...but it is continuous in each branch, right?